# Why I can't see hair in exported glTF file?

Tags: particles, export, hair, gltf

I created hair - **Particle Settings** and I would like to see them in exported glTF file. 
I tried to made Mesh from this hair, but it seems that doesn't help. Still I can't see the hair in exported file. 
Could please someone help me? I would be really very thankful.

[image]

Comment: Converting the particles to a mesh ought to work... If not, this may be a bug, and I'd suggest filing an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) and including the `.blend` file, you can drag ZIP files into GitHub comments.

Comment: Converting the particles to a mesh works, but I don't know, why I can't see the hair in exported .obj or .glTF.
Thank you for answering.